# Run FMU simulation using FMI Library

Tags: fmi

I have an FMU zip file which I exported from Openmodelica. I am a quite newbie with FMUs and FMI and could not find the way in the documentation how to run a simulation using FMI Library.

In FMU SDK, it is easier to run an FMU zip file through "fmusim" command. But I want to run the simulation using FMI Library from Modelon. Could you help me how can I do that?

Comment: If you need a high level interface you might want to try `PyFMI`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be better to tag FMI Library instead of OpenModelica.
You mean OpenModelica documentation doesn't say how to run a simulation using FMI Library?

FMI Library doesn't have any executable program. It is a library and you need to use it in your own code to import FMUs. There are some test programs in the repository with examples on how to use the library.

Comment: The executable program using the FMI Library is the FMU Compliance Checker (https://fmi-standard.org/downloads)

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to run the *.FMU file through FMI Library. I have found a test model named "fmi2_import_cs_test" to have an idea how to run this. Thanking you again.